# Heatmap error: 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Tags: r, heatmap

My data set which looks like this

```
            ScorePCC     ScoreRP118AB40        ScorePCAB40       ScorePCAB42     ScoreRP118AB42        ScoreRP118C
1  0.505292370431885 -0.487102577128298  0.507809334891816 0.747443655982329 -0.535789275529111 -0.716261545478814
2 0.0460853793217228 -0.565826519317086  0.603256505343961 0.521148719292688  -0.70403715420595  -1.22380395524847
3 -0.201883736374525  0.114865679916836  0.538392265862292 0.279877772464927 -0.447006711967553  -1.18403025050545
4  0.150790415921752   2.73363683054763  0.115208291453019 0.282046975578209   1.23752444573667   1.15590811140552
5                  0                  0                  0                 0                  0                  0
6  0.385967553382327   3.05220411518835 -0.974816617012186 0.278666976145095   2.23470633791445   2.22002371949737
```

When I try to generate a heatmap using `heatmap(df)`

It produces this error

> Error in heatmap(df) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

When I then try `heatmap(as.matrix(df[, -1]))`

It produces the same error

> Error in heatmap(as.matrix(df[, -1])) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

How do I fix this to generate the heatmap?

Comment: Quick answer : `heatmap(as.matrix(df[-1 , ]))` . When you do `df[ , -1 ]` you remove the first column while it is the first row you need to set aside to have a numeric matrix.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I tried running that but it still gave me the same response sadly

Comment: Then you may want to check what type is actually your data with `str( as.matrix(df[-1 , ]) )`. My guess is it is a character matrix. Convert it to numeric with `as.numeric( as.matrix(df[-1 , ]) )`